# jquery locate the button on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<button onclick="func()"></button>
```

and I want to locate the button element in func(), but when I use `$(this)` it seems that it always refer to the window object. Then what's the good practice to locate the element being clicked?

Comment: do you want to Locate the button ...as in focus on the button get its colour changed ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `event.target` to get the button element inside `func` function. Then you can convert to jQuery object. For example, in code below, I get buttons `id`.

```
function func(){
    var button = $(event.target);
    console.log(button.attr("id"));
}
```

```js
function func(){
 var button = $(event.target);
 console.log(button.attr("id"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="func()" id="button1">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function func($this){
  alert($($this).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="test" onclick="func(this)">click</button>
```